# TFX trainer component running in Kubeflow fails although it was successful in the Interactive Context

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines, tensorflow-extended

In GCP I run a Kubeflow ML pipeline with TFX components using a custom service account. The pipeline reads data from BigQuery and it has the following components:
components = [example_gen, statistics_gen, schema_gen, transform, **trainer**, pusher]

The main problem is that it fails at the last "trainer" step, although I tested each step in the interactive context and all were OK.
The secondary problem is that I cannot display log messages for the trainer module execution code in the main GCP pipeline dashboard (in the logs area).
This complicates my debugging attempts. I can only view the logs from Logs Explorer but I cannot display the messages for the python trainer module code, seem only to be the framework messages.
In those messages I view only one type of error message. I identified that this operation uses the default service account (not the custom one) and it might not have all permissions needed. I tried to set the trainer component to use the custom SA but it does not use it. How can I set it properly for the custom SA?

> com.google.cloud.ai.platform.common.errors.AiPlatformException:
> code=ALREADY_EXISTS, message=Schema with name
> projects/2385..../locations/..../metadataStores/default/metadataSchemas/f14caf7e-4234-473d-ac31-....
> and version 0.0.1 already exists., cause=null

[image]

The code for the trained module file:

```
%%writefile {_trainer_module_file}

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
import tensorflow_transform as tft
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import schema_utils
from tfx_bsl.tfxio import dataset_options
from tfx.components.trainer.executor import Executor
from tfx.dsl.components.base import executor_spec

from typing import List
from absl import logging
# from tensorflow import keras

from tfx import v1 as tfx
from tfx_bsl.public import tfxio

from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import schema_pb2

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.info("This is an informational log message.")
logging.warning("This is a warning log message.")
logging.error("This is an error log message.")



# Categorical features are assumed to each have a maximum value in the dataset.
_MAX_CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_VALUES = [3]

_CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_KEYS = [
    'F_1'
]

_DENSE_FLOAT_FEATURE_KEYS = ['F_2', 'F_3']

# Number of buckets used by tf.transform for encoding each feature.
_FEATURE_BUCKET_COUNT = 5

_BUCKET_FEATURE_KEYS = [
    'F_2'
]

# Number of vocabulary terms used for encoding VOCAB_FEATURES by tf.transform
_VOCAB_SIZE = 1000

# Count of out-of-vocab buckets in which unrecognized VOCAB_FEATURES are hashed.
_OOV_SIZE = 10

_VOCAB_FEATURE_KEYS = [
    'F_1',
]

# Keys
_LABEL_KEY = 'F_LABEL'

print('_LABEL_KEY',_LABEL_KEY)
###########


# Tf.Transform considers these features as "raw"
def _get_raw_feature_spec(schema):
  return schema_utils.schema_as_feature_spec(schema).feature_spec


def _build_estimator(config, hidden_units=None, warm_start_from=None):
  """Build an estimator for predicting the tipping behavior of taxi riders.
  Args:
    config: tf.estimator.RunConfig defining the runtime environment for the
      estimator (including model_dir).
    hidden_units: [int], the layer sizes of the DNN (input layer first)
    warm_start_from: Optional directory to warm start from.
  Returns:
    A dict of the following:
      - estimator: The estimator that will be used for training and eval.
      - train_spec: Spec for training.
      - eval_spec: Spec for eval.
      - eval_input_receiver_fn: Input function for eval.
  """
  real_valued_columns = [
      tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key, shape=())
      for key in _DENSE_FLOAT_FEATURE_KEYS
  ]
    
    
  categorical_columns = [
      tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(  # pylint: disable=g-complex-comprehension
          key,
          num_buckets=num_buckets,
          default_value=0) for key, num_buckets in zip(
              _CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_KEYS,
              _MAX_CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_VALUES)
  ]
  return tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
      config=config,
      linear_feature_columns=categorical_columns,
      dnn_feature_columns=real_valued_columns,
      dnn_hidden_units=hidden_units or [100, 70, 50, 25],
      warm_start_from=warm_start_from)


def _example_serving_receiver_fn(tf_transform_graph, schema):
  """Build the serving in inputs.
  Args:
    tf_transform_graph: A TFTransformOutput.
    schema: the schema of the input data.
  Returns:
    Tensorflow graph which parses examples, applying tf-transform to them.
  """
  raw_feature_spec = _get_raw_feature_spec(schema)
  raw_feature_spec.pop(_LABEL_KEY)

  raw_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
      raw_feature_spec, default_batch_size=None)
  serving_input_receiver = raw_input_fn()

  transformed_features = tf_transform_graph.transform_raw_features(
      serving_input_receiver.features)

  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
      transformed_features, serving_input_receiver.receiver_tensors)


def _eval_input_receiver_fn(tf_transform_graph, schema):
  """Build everything needed for the tf-model-analysis to run the model.
  Args:
    tf_transform_graph: A TFTransformOutput.
    schema: the schema of the input data.
  Returns:
    EvalInputReceiver function, which contains:
      - Tensorflow graph which parses raw untransformed features, applies the
        tf-transform preprocessing operators.
      - Set of raw, untransformed features.
      - Label against which predictions will be compared.
  """
  # Notice that the inputs are raw features, not transformed features here.
  raw_feature_spec = _get_raw_feature_spec(schema)

  serialized_tf_example = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(
      dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_example_tensor')

  # Add a parse_example operator to the tensorflow graph, which will parse
  # raw, untransformed, tf examples.
  features = tf.io.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, raw_feature_spec)

  # Now that we have our raw examples, process them through the tf-transform
  # function computed during the preprocessing step.
  transformed_features = tf_transform_graph.transform_raw_features(
      features)

  # The key name MUST be 'examples'.
  receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}

  # NOTE: Model is driven by transformed features (since training works on the
  # materialized output of TFT, but slicing will happen on raw features.
  features.update(transformed_features)

  return tfma.export.EvalInputReceiver(
      features=features,
      receiver_tensors=receiver_tensors,
      labels=transformed_features[_LABEL_KEY])


def _input_fn(file_pattern, data_accessor, tf_transform_output, batch_size=200):
  """Generates features and label for tuning/training.

  Args:
    file_pattern: List of paths or patterns of input tfrecord files.
    data_accessor: DataAccessor for converting input to RecordBatch.
    tf_transform_output: A TFTransformOutput.
    batch_size: representing the number of consecutive elements of returned
      dataset to combine in a single batch

  Returns:
    A dataset that contains (features, indices) tuple where features is a
      dictionary of Tensors, and indices is a single Tensor of label indices.
  """
  return data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory(
      file_pattern,
      dataset_options.TensorFlowDatasetOptions(
          batch_size=batch_size, label_key=_LABEL_KEY),
      tf_transform_output.transformed_metadata.schema)


# TFX will call this function
def trainer_fn(trainer_fn_args, schema):
  """Build the estimator using the high level API.
  Args:
    trainer_fn_args: Holds args used to train the model as name/value pairs.
    schema: Holds the schema of the training examples.
  Returns:
    A dict of the following:
      - estimator: The estimator that will be used for training and eval.
      - train_spec: Spec for training.
      - eval_spec: Spec for eval.
      - eval_input_receiver_fn: Input function for eval.
  """
  # Number of nodes in the first layer of the DNN
  first_dnn_layer_size = 100
  num_dnn_layers = 4
  dnn_decay_factor = 0.7

  train_batch_size = 40
  eval_batch_size = 40

  tf_transform_graph = tft.TFTransformOutput(trainer_fn_args.transform_output)

  train_input_fn = lambda: _input_fn(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      trainer_fn_args.train_files,
      trainer_fn_args.data_accessor,
      tf_transform_graph,
      batch_size=train_batch_size)

  eval_input_fn = lambda: _input_fn(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      trainer_fn_args.eval_files,
      trainer_fn_args.data_accessor,
      tf_transform_graph,
      batch_size=eval_batch_size)

  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      train_input_fn,
      max_steps=trainer_fn_args.train_steps)

  serving_receiver_fn = lambda: _example_serving_receiver_fn(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      tf_transform_graph, schema)

  exporter = tf.estimator.FinalExporter('etl-trainer', serving_receiver_fn)
  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
      eval_input_fn,
      steps=trainer_fn_args.eval_steps,
      exporters=[exporter],
      name='etl-eval')

  run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
      save_checkpoints_steps=999, keep_checkpoint_max=1)

  run_config = run_config.replace(model_dir=trainer_fn_args.serving_model_dir)

  estimator = _build_estimator(
      # Construct layers sizes with exponetial decay
      hidden_units=[
          max(2, int(first_dnn_layer_size * dnn_decay_factor**i))
          for i in range(num_dnn_layers)
      ],
      config=run_config,
      warm_start_from=trainer_fn_args.base_model)

  # Create an input receiver for TFMA processing
  receiver_fn = lambda: _eval_input_receiver_fn(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      tf_transform_graph, schema)

  return {
      'estimator': estimator,
      'train_spec': train_spec,
      'eval_spec': eval_spec,
      'eval_input_receiver_fn': receiver_fn
  }
```

The TFX trainer component:

```
  # Uses user-provided Python function that trains a model.
  trainer = tfx.components.Trainer(
    module_file=trainer_module_file, 
    custom_executor_spec=executor_spec.ExecutorClassSpec(Executor),
    examples=transform.outputs['transformed_examples'],
    schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'],
    transform_graph=transform.outputs['transform_graph'],
    train_args=tfx.proto.TrainArgs(num_steps=100),
    eval_args=tfx.proto.EvalArgs(num_steps=10))
```

The pipeline:

```
runner = tfx.orchestration.experimental.KubeflowV2DagRunner(
    config=tfx.orchestration.experimental.KubeflowV2DagRunnerConfig(),
    output_filename=PIPELINE_DEFINITION_FILE)
_ = runner.run(
    _create_pipeline(
        pipeline_name=PIPELINE_NAME,
        pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
        query=QUERY,
        trainer_module_file=os.path.join(MODULE_ROOT, _trainer_module_file),
        transform_module_file=os.path.join(MODULE_ROOT, _etl_transform_module_file),
        serving_model_dir=SERVING_MODEL_DIR,
        beam_pipeline_args=BIG_QUERY_WITH_DIRECT_RUNNER_BEAM_PIPELINE_ARGS))
```

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.